# Multi-step Calculation in a Formula

Tags: formula

I have a calculation I'm trying to put into a formula that has multi-steps. I have the Total number in a custom field called Likelihood_c this adds the values together but now I need to calculate that value

Overall Calculation but 1-5 shows how to break it down. Is there a way to add this to a formula

1 / (1 + 1 / EXP(Likelihood_c - 5.31))

1. Reference Likelihood_c field and Subtract 5.31
2. ex (where x is #1 result)
3. 1 / result of #2
4. Add 1 to result of #3
5. 1 / result of #4

Does it need to be 2 separate formulas
1st formula
(Likelihood_c - 5.31) *EXP

2nd Formula
(1/ Answer from 1st formula) + 1 /1 = final answer

Comment: Everything in your example looks achievable to me. Have you tried making your formula? Note that EXP takes an argument (the power you're raising _e_ to). https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5

Comment: You don't need to split it into 2 formulas. Just enclose the EXP function within paranthesis.

Comment: Here is what i have written: EXP(Likelihood__c - 5.31) /1 + 1 /1